# I can't connect to WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless

Hi I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 but i had porblems with my WiFi adapter.
I can see all networks but when i tried to connect it just keept connecting. And nothing happend

Here is output from lshw

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 7
       bus info: pci@0000:04:07.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: a0:f3:c1:df:b6:af
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-53-generic firmware=N/A latency=168 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:21 memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
```